# Advancing tensorflow dataset iterator in python multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is there any way to move the iterator in this example?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def store(batch, queue):
    while True:
        queue.put(batch)


if __name__=='__main__':
    pqueue = Queue()
    a1 = np.arange(1000)

    m = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a1).repeat().batch(1)
    iter_m = m.make_one_shot_iterator()
    m_init_ops = iter_m.make_initializer(m)
    next_m = iter_m.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        batch = sess.run(next_m)
        pp_process = Process(target=store,args=(batch, pqueue,))
        pp_process.daemon = True
        pp_process.start()

        for i in range(10):
            print(pqueue.get())
```

My idea is to store processed data in the queue that can be accessed by tensorflow for training, unfortunately I could not advance the iterator. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

The current output is

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tensorflow multithreading

The iterator is not advancing since you are technically only executing the get_next operation once: `sess.run(next_m)`. If you were only using tensorflow multithreading, you could have obtained the desired results by simply moving it into the `store` function:

```
def store(sess, next_m, queue):
    while True:
        queue.put(sess.run(next_m))

# batch = sess.run(next_m) <- Remove
pp_process = Thread(target=store,args=(sess, next_m, pqueue,)) # <- Thread with correct args passed
```

### Tensorflow multiprocessing

However, for multiprocessing, you should also ensure that you never instantiate (fork) a new process after already having created a session since the session object is not serializable.
In your case, you can simply create a new session in the store function and start the main session after forking:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def store(next_m, queue):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        while True:
            queue.put(sess.run(next_m))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    pp_process = Process(target=store, args=(next_m, pqueue,))
    pp_process.daemon = True
    pp_process.start() # <- Fork before starting this session!

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in range(10):
            print(pqueue.get())
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions. I updated the code as you have suggested. It gave a TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects and EOFError: Ran out of input. Have you tried to run the updated code?

Comment: @wontleave Oh! That's because you can't serialize tensorflow sessions. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry your modified code gave the same errors as before. Thanks anyway

Comment: @wontleave Uploaded the complete file [here](https://gist.github.com/reubenjohn/7ab84fdb282d74366e0d4994a5e4ee09). I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're facing.

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu and it works great thanks. The errors should be related to my tensorflow in Visual Studio.